# Should i use for each loop/cursor in SQL or a regular one in Java? What is more efficient?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, performance

Hello stackoverflow i have a doubt, which is the proper way to solve this?

I have this sql sentence:

```
SELECT *
FROM task
   , subject
WHERE task.id_subject = task.id
    AND task.id_tasktype = 1
    AND subject.id_evaluation = {ALL the ids of table evaluation}
```

If i want to execute this sentence for every evaluation what is more efficient? a loop/cursor or whatever in SQL (i have basic knowledge of sql) or a regular for each in Java?

Comment: A for loop in java is preferred over Loop/cursor in SQL. Writing cursor is SQL dependent and if you want to scale your app later, it will be difficult. You can use loop in Java for now, but this loop can be converted into parallel tasks, for scaling your application

Comment: A set based approach is favourable over loops in either tier - will an `IN` work for you? And please consider using the ANSI-92 `JOIN` syntax instead of joining in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Neither.  Write a single SQL statement that does it all.  That's what SQL is all about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your situation. Basically, if your database server and application server are actually two different computers, then you might decide to run the loop at the server which can handle more pressure. You need to look at some statistics to be able to determine this.

Also, you can implement both solutions and measure the time needed at db server + time needed at application server. If one of your loops is consistently quicker than the other, then it is practically more efficient in the scenario you are running it according to your experiments. Off course, the scenario might change over time.

Generally speaking, people tend to run this loop on the application server (Java), since you might need to execute some things available only there in the future, but if you have a very good reason to run this on the database server, like the case when a trigger should trigger this functionality, then you might decide to run it there.

Basically, you are trying to optimize a loop where you do not necessarily have a problem. If you encounter performance issues, then you might decide to experiment with a few things, including, but not limited to the suggestions shown in your question.